# Upload file using jquery ajax, and get result in $_FILES

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to upload file using, I tried this but it's not working and also not giving me the result in $_POST on result page.

```
$.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'../investor/archive2.php',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                tmp_dir:'tmp',
                //dataType: 'json',
                processData: false, // Don't process the files
                //contentType: false,
                 cache: false,
                data:'action='+action+'&title='+title+'&datetime='+datetime+'&name='+docfile,
                success:function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
```

Comment: give this a try [http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/](http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/)

Comment: you need to pass the data in json format , like this `data:{'action':action,'title':title .........}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use Form data if you are using AJAX.

```
var data = new FormData()
data.append( 'photo', $('#photo')[0].files[0] ); //photo is the name and id of the <input type="file">
data.append( 'action', action);
data.append( 'title', title);    
.
.
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",                
   url: "../investor/archive2.php",
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   cache:false,
   data: data,
   success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: how to send multiple files using this ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. U mean u have to send multiple files at a time?

Comment: yeah, at the same time i have to post multiple files also

Comment: It is possible in PHP.. u have to use move_uploaded_file

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery form plugin to handle file uploads through Ajax, files data will be available at the action under $_FILES if you submit a form using that plugin through Ajax.

Plugin Link: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Sample Code:

```
$('#form_id').ajaxForm(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
  console.log(data);
});
```